# Code working in local environment, but didn't work when hosted on iis

Tags: asp.net

Requiremnet--on click of a button, a site will be created on iis.I am passing a name,that will become the name of the site on iis

I created a powershell script to do this.Using process.start, i want to open a powershell.exe and want to execute my code inside it.
Code...

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        Char[] chr = Password.ToCharArray();
        System.Security.SecureString pwd = new System.Security.SecureString();

        foreach (char c in chr)
        {
            pwd.AppendChar(c);
        }

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";

        //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = powershellScriptCode;  //It contains powershell script       to        create a new website in iis
        proc.StartInfo.UserName = UserName;  //Comes from config file
        proc.StartInfo.Password = pwd;        //Comes from config file
        proc.StartInfo.Domain = Domain;      //Comes from config file
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        bool result = proc.Start();
```

when i run this code in local environment,it run sucessfully and creates a website, but when i run this code on IIS(After hosting), it is not able to create a site on IIS.so what type of permissions i required.

Comment: Is Powershell.exe installed and available? Which Windows version is it?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...Yes powershell is already installed..i am using version 1.0 of powershell and Windows server 2008 R2 standard

Comment: Same code sucessfully run in console application and window form..but not in website (When hosted on IIS).Thats why i think there must be some permission issue..

Comment: Can't you simply try to give Administrator permissions to your website and see if it works (and then remove the permissions)? Then you know that it is a permission issue and so can create a user with the minimal required permissions (because it is not recommendable to run a website as admin).

Comment: sorry to say...But can u tell me how can i give administrative permissions to my website...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the identitiy in the Application Pool. Go to IIS Manager -> Application Pools -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Identity. Change it to "Local system" and try again (but remember to change it back unless you know what you are doing, security-wise; if it works, create a user account with just the required permissions).

Comment: Everything Except powershell part of code is not working..Still i am not able to create a website....

Comment: Try to change the Identity to Administrator and see what happens. Or can you start another, simpler Powershell script?

Comment: Everything Except powershell part of code is not working..Still i am not able to create a website....When i debug in local environment,then i am able to create website using powershell.Diagonistic.process is able to open a powerscript window and my site created sucessfully, but when i hosted on iis,its not working...When i debug my hosted site,i figured out that process is not able to open a powershell window.

Comment: No powershell script is working....even system.diagonistics.process is not able to open powershell window(In hosted env.) but in local environment it is working..I am testing changing identity to administration...

Comment: Not able to find administrator in identity..so i use custom account and provide administrative username and password..but its not working

Comment: Dump a set of all environment variables in hosted as well as in local environment and check if there are relevant differences.

Comment: I am hosting in same environment(both local and hosting pc are same)

Comment: Hi olaf..its not working...So i dropped the idea...Now using Window service...Please have a look at my second question..I posted the whole code and comment